# SQL ERROR Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, sql

Where am I going wrong?

If I do this

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(AVG(`payper`),2)) AS `Average Pay` 
FROM `rep_commission` 
WHERE type IN (SELECT type ='TV','NET','FONE')
```

I get

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

If I try this,

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(AVG(payper),2)) AS Average Pay
FROM rep_commission WHERE type=('TV', 'NET', 'FONE')
```

I get

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

If I try this,

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(AVG(`payper`),2)) AS `Average Pay` FROM `rep_commission` WHERE type='TV', 'NET', 'FONE'
```

I get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'NET', 'FONE'' at line 1

If I do,

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(AVG(`payper`),2)) AS `Average Pay` FROM `rep_commission` WHERE type='TV'
```

I get

> Average Pay
>
> $99.99

Which is what I am after, but the ONE type...

Google, Chat, and other SO questions lead me to the previous attempts that get Operand ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because you are doing it wrong. You should be using a `IN` operator like below since `=` operator can work with only a single value and not multiple values

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(AVG(payper),2)) AS `Average Pay`
FROM rep_commission WHERE type IN ('TV', 'NET', 'FONE')
```

In your first query as well where you say below is totally wrong

```
WHERE type IN (SELECT type ='TV','NET','FONE')
```

It should rather be

```
WHERE type IN (
SELECT 'TV'
UNION 
SELECT 'NET'
UNION
SELECT 'FONE')
```

(OR) Simply

```
WHERE type IN ('TV', 'NET', 'FONE')
```

Comment: Ahh! I tried doing "WHERE type IN (SELECT type ='TV','NET','FONE')", I see where I made the mistake. Thank you :)